# Java pass by reference vs pass by value trouble

Tags: java

why am i getting an error in the pass by reference example `obj1.add200really` is underlined

```
public class Test {

    private int number;

    Test(){
        number = 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj1 = new Test();
        System.out.println("the number is " + obj1.number);
        System.out.println("the number 1 plus 200 is " + obj1.add200(obj1.number));
        System.out.println("while the number is still " + obj1.number);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("the number is " + obj1.number);
        System.out.println("the number 1 plus 200 is " + obj1.add200really(obj1.number));
        System.out.println("while the number is still " + obj1.number);
    }


int add200(int somenumber){
    somenumber = somenumber + 200;
    return somenumber;
}
int add200really(Test myobj){
    myobj.number = 999;
    return myobj.number;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `obj1.add200really(obj1);`

Comment: @user133466 - I don't think so because you do not know the basic facts - **Java is always pass-by-value**. Please read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: `someObj.func(someObj)` is almost never the right thing to do. @user133466 I don't think you have understood the problem, leave alone the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no method `add200really(int)`

Your method `add200really()` requires an object. You're trying to call it with an `int`